# What are the risks of not specifying font size in an HTML email?

Tags: css, html-email, font-size

I have been building HTML emails for some time and have always specified font sizes in my code, e.g.

```
<h1 style="font-size: 24px">Hello Readers!</h1>
<p  style="font-size: 16px">Welcome to 2021!</p>
```

However browsers and email clients (Gmail, Outlook.com, Mail on iOS etc) all seem to do a good job of applying appropriate styling based on HTML tags. E.g. Content in the `h1` and `p` tags of the following are sized as you would expect, even though `font-size` information is absent from the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Font Size Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Readers!</h1>
    <p>It's been a long year...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming content relevant HTML tags are being used (`h1`, `h2`, `p` etc.), what are the risks of omitting `font-size` from HTML email code, effectively delegating this to the client / browser?

The most obvious danger seems to be that all your text would be the same size if no default values were applied, but this seems unlikely in the real world?

**Edit:**

The motivation for this question is whether readability might be improved by allowing the client / browser to dictate font sizing, rather than hard-coding this into the email, e.g. the [comment below from @stephen-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208558/what-are-the-risks-of-not-specifying-font-size-in-an-html-email?noredirect=1#comment117099171_66208558).

Comment: Yeah ideally it would have the same font size for all the text in the email except the header tags they may seems bigger, but its also possible that it takes the font size from its parent container. Try to inspect your email in your inbox and you will see that they are always enclosed in some container which may differ from client to client. In my case all the font sizes were became same and the font was different in mobile view and desktop view for the same email.

Comment: `unlikely in the real world?` that is correct. The real world is not fun when it comes to HTML email. Inline styles is the best way to go. Outlook.com even changes the color of headings if not specified.

Comment: Conversely, What are the risks **of specifying** font size in an HTML email? — I absolutely _hate_ getting email where every single paragraph has `<p  style="font-size: 10px">` applied. Why? Because 10px is too small for me to read and with size specified _every time_ I can't adjust it globally. Yes, there is browser zoom, but that also magnifies the email client controls to be too large. `</gripe>` _...and_ using a `<style>` block in the `<head>` so sizes aren't repeated is pretty well supported — https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/

Comment: Good comment thanks @StephenP - this was my motivation for asking the question. Have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely get surprising results.

I tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Font Size Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Readers!</h1>
    <p>It's been a long year...</p>
    <h2>In other news</h2>
    <p><span>This is done with a p and span</span></p>
    <h3>Now we're h3</h3>
    <strong>and let's try strong text</strong>
    <h4>But wait, there's more</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>This is <u>in a</u> table with a <a href="https://www.google.com">link</a> too</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    This is without any tag
</body>
</html>
```

And got no font-size from the header tags in Samsung:

[image: Samsung screenshot]

Of course, not specifying font-family also turns up some pretty strange results--Times New Roman is the default for Outlook desktops (& freenet.de):

[image: Outlook screenshot]

And different font-families have different font sizes. Not specifying line-height also will change heights of paragraphs, which can impact your design.

But otherwise pretty typical response--this from Apple Mail:

[image: Apple Mail screenshot]

This (below) from Mail.ru I thought had quite a lot of margin, because we did not specify that either.

[image: Mail.ru screenshot]

The link was sometimes underlined in the tests, sometimes not.

All-in-all if you are not specifying font-size (although Samsung at the very least needs it), you'll find yourself needing to specify everything else anyway, so why not font-size too?

**Update**

I got Samsung to work when inserting just a standard wrapper. So leaving out font-size works well for everything.

However, if you want to specify the font-size *once* in a `<style>` tag, that will work for everything *except Gmail IMAP/POP users*. (There are different Gmail versions: check https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2019/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-2019-edition/)

Here's the code I used that worked in Samsung, and with specifying font-size once. Notice also you have to be careful to capture all tags you use - text not within the tag obviously won't get picked up (e.g. just in a td if you haven't specified a font-size for td too).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Font Size Test</title>
    <style>p {font-size: 24px}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">
        <div style="max-width:600px;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;" >
            <![endif]-->
            <table align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <h1>Hello Readers!</h1>
    <p>It's been a long year...</p>
    <h2>In other news</h2>
    <p><span>This is done with a p and span</span></p>
    <h3>Now we're h3</h3>
    <strong>and let's try strong text</strong>
    <h4>But wait, there's more</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>This is <u>in a</u> table with a <a href="https://www.google.com">link</a> too</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    This is without any tag
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answer thanks @Nathan. I've added my motivation for asking this question, i.e. whether user experience might be improved by allowing the client / browser to control font size. 

RE other attributes, I think there is a distinction between font family (for example) which can just be specified in one place, and font size, which needs to be added to each tag and so is more likely to lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: I think the examples you've given (aside from Samsung mail) are all legible with reasonable style distinctions between each tag, which would suggest that in most cases, omitting font-size tags does not impact (and may even improve) user experience / readability.

Comment: But the takeaway is that based on the Samsung example, you do really need to specify font size in your code to ensure distinctions between the different tags.

Comment: @MattSaunders Actually, specifying a standard wrap fixes it for Samsung. Nevertheless, Gmail IMAP does not support `<style>` at all, so if you did want to change the defaults, there's just that one.